# is there any difference in reading from a file or string variable

Tags: java, string, file

I am reading from a file which contains several lines of string. I am checking the strings, line by line vs a predefined value. My concern in the required time which is so high. I was thinking of copying the file's content in a local string value and continue with this variable instead of reading from a file. is it going to change the performance of the code?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Have you measured performance? How performance-critical is this code? What are your performance targets? Without knowing the answers to these questions and without seeing *any* of the code involved, I'm afraid it's impossible to answer this question in any meaningful way.

Comment: If you're copying the code to a String variable first (I assume by reading the file), then doing your logic, I'd imagine that would be slower as you're adding an extra step.

Comment: Your request is way too broad - and unclear. Of course, when you read that file **each time** you make these comparisons, then that is probably a problem. But then: we cant help with such input. Consider putting up a real [mcve] that shows us the code that you think is "too slow".

Comment: Post the code, quick.

Comment: thanks for your reply, My main concern is the difference of reading from an external file or an internal variable. Do they matter in case of timing?

Answer (score 1):

You should read by line. Use BufferedReader or Scanner then performance will be the same as reading full file. But if you read full file you are limited with file size, it simply may not fit in memory

Comment: that's right but opening the file, reading it and closing it in an iteration seams time taking, Thanks for your reply anyway, I am going to check the performance of different sections of the code now,